# Error cannot allocate big buffer for dag

Tags: mining, claymore

Someone can help me? It's nvidia 920mx, my laptop model is Asus x441u.

[image]

Comment: Check in the page of Asus how much memory has your graphic card. Mining with 2Gbytes is not feasible since a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop GPU has too little VRAM in order to load the DAG into memory. That being said even if it could load the DAG into memory, mining with laptop GPUs is ill-advised as most models are not equipped to deal with that amount of heat generation.

Comment: Hi there. Do you have a reference/source for the part about heat generation?

Comment: The law of thermodynamics and closed systems like laptops which  historically have subpar cooling solutions :P